# android sqlite3 prob: no such column:d6a43948e4

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

All:

I got a problem when using android SQLite database.

This is the error log:

> No such column: d6a43948e4:  SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE
>   user_object_id=d6a43948e4

I think I don't query the column d6a43948e4, I just need the data which the value of user_object_id is d6a43948e4.

Can anybody tell me what's going on?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may want to show the code to get more precise help, but unless you're using parameters which you probably should, string literals need to be quoted with `'`, so `WHERE user_object_id='d6a43948e4'` would work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you give an example of your code, it will be more easier to answer but  '...' quotation mark may be missing.

For example try this in your code; user_object_id='d6a43948e4'

Comment: You are right. I missed the quotation mark. Thx a lot!